# Can someone help me with replacing the cursor in the following SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, cursor

This is the SQL code that goes through a table that contains various records with a start and end data like a slowly changing dimension. While checking the dimension we found out that sometimes the start date is not following the end date. So we loop the table and recreate the start/end dates to make sure the start/end date is actually the min/max of the available dates. But the process takes too long to work through 9 million rows. I would love to use a while loop but can't figure out to retain the min/max value and detect the switch in ID.

```
DECLARE @MINDDEB Datetime
DECLARE @DDEB Datetime
DECLARE @DFIN Datetime
DECLARE @CECV float
DECLARE @AIDNEBHNPRPEP int
DECLARE @CETA float
DECLARE @AIDNEBHNPRAFI int
DECLARE @MAXDFIN Datetime
DECLARE @OLDCECV float
DECLARE @OLDAIDNEBHNPRPEP int
DECLARE @OLDCETA float
DECLARE @OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI int

SET @MINDDEB=9999-12-31
SET @MAXDFIN=1835-12-31
drop table dbo.TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS_CURSORTABLE
--T2
SELECT DDEB, DFIN, CETA,AIDNEBHNPRAFI 
into dbo.TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS_CURSORTABLE
FROM dbo.TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS
WHERE  AIDNEBHNPRAFI=-1
ORDER BY AIDNEBHNPRAFI,DDEB

DECLARE T2_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
select   DDEB, DFIN, CETA,AIDNEBHNPRAFI 
from TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS
where DFIN>DDEB and BRRDDEL<>1 and CSTUVRS = 1 --and AIDNEBHNPRAFI in (1080,1033143,2311904)
order by AIDNEBHNPRAFI,DDEB,CETA,CECV


OPEN T2_CURSOR  

FETCH NEXT FROM T2_CURSOR   
INTO @DDEB,  @DFIN, @CETA,@AIDNEBHNPRAFI
SET @OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI=@AIDNEBHNPRAFI
SET @OLDCETA=@CETA  
--SET   @OLDCECV=@CECV

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    if ( @OLDCETA=@CETA and @OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI=@AIDNEBHNPRAFI) 
    BEGIN
        --print 'entering first if'
        IF (@MINDDEB>@DDEB) 
        BEGIN
            SET @MINDDEB=@DDEB
        END
        IF (@MAXDFIN<@DFIN) 
        BEGIN       
            SET @MAXDFIN=@DFIN
        END
    END
    --print ' OLD CECV '+convert(varchar(10),@OLDCECV) +' new CECV '+ convert(varchar(10),@CECV) +' OLDAID '+ convert(varchar(10),@OLDAIDNEBHNPRPEP) +' NEWAID '+ convert(varchar(10),@AIDNEBHNPRPEP)
    -- +' NEWDDEB '+ convert(varchar(10),@DDEB,101) +' MINDDEB '+ convert(varchar(10),@MINDDEB,101) +' NEWDFIn '+ convert(varchar(10),@DFIN,101) +' MAXDFIN '+ convert(varchar(10),@MAXDFIN,101)



 FETCH NEXT FROM T2_CURSOR   
    INTO   @DDEB,  @DFIN, @CETA,@AIDNEBHNPRAFI

    if ( @OLDCETA<>@CETA or @OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI<>@AIDNEBHNPRAFI) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS_CURSORTABLE (DDEB, DFIN, CETA,AIDNEBHNPRAFI )
        VALUES (@MINDDEB,@MAXDFIN,@OLDCETA,@OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI)
        SET @OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI=@AIDNEBHNPRAFI
        --SET   @OLDCECV=@CECV
        SET @OLDCETA=@CETA
        SET @MINDDEB=@DDEB
        SET @MAXDFIN=@DFIN
    END


END   
INSERT INTO TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS_CURSORTABLE (DDEB, DFIN, CETA,AIDNEBHNPRAFI )
        VALUES (@MINDDEB,@MAXDFIN,@OLDCETA,@OLDAIDNEBHNPRAFI)
CLOSE T2_CURSOR;  
DEALLOCATE T2_CURSOR;
```

This is the source data
DDEB    DFIN    CETA    AIDNEBHNPRAFI
2006-03-01 00:00:00.000 2006-04-30 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2006-05-01 00:00:00.000 2006-11-30 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2006-12-01 00:00:00.000 2007-04-30 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2007-05-01 00:00:00.000 2008-04-30 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2008-05-01 00:00:00.000 2008-08-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2008-09-01 00:00:00.000 2008-10-31 23:59:59.000 2   231272
2008-11-01 00:00:00.000 2009-04-30 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2009-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000 14  231272

and this is the result we get with the cursor

DDEB    DFIN    CETA    AIDNEBHNPRAFI
2006-03-01 00:00:00.000 2008-08-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2008-09-01 00:00:00.000 2008-10-31 23:59:59.000 2   231272
2008-11-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000 14  231272

Comment: Either simplify and minimize the question, or hire somebody.

Comment: @jarlh, your comment looks to be advertisement to me as you say *or hire somebody* ... :)

Comment: @Rahul, but I'm not this somebody.

Comment: It's a difficult time and a long post to read....try running your code with FAST_FORWARD after DECLARE T2_CURSOR CURSOR and check whether you have a better performance or not

Comment: @Kostis, thanks I will try that.

Comment: Adding fast forward is not going to help much here. The performance problem is because of the cursor. And using a while loop is an exercise in futility. You would be replacing one  slow process with a very slightly different slow process.

Comment: @SeanLange sure it is not going to run in 1sec but the cursor's performance is much better with FAST_FORWARD. I don;t have a clear mind now to propose an overall better implementation :)

Comment: It may help but it will be very minimal. This needs to be a set based solution.

Comment: I can probably help but the names of everything are so unbelievably hostile it makes me want to slit my wrists. Are these seriously the names of your objects?

Comment: Sean, that is the table naming convention my customer uses. These are tables that come from mainframe through SAS into SQL :-(
I tried using the names of the fields as much as possible to make it readible to my colleagues.
What I want to do is keep the min of the start date, max of the end date per occurence. And insert a record in a temporary table if the ID of the record (AIDNEBHNPRAFI ) or a value (CETA) changes. This works but it takes almost 5 hours to process 9 million rows.

Comment: OK. Can you mock up the tables and some sample **not real** data so we have a few rows to work with? It would really helpful if you could provide the desired output for the sample data. I will help you turn this into set based process instead of the agonizingly slow (yet functional) RBAR cursor.

Comment: I added the source and result table for 1 ID. You can see that the value of CETA changes from 1 to 2 back to 1 later on. If you do a min/max of the dates then the last date range becomes an overlap in date ranges. That is why I started the cursor loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt.  The results returned match, but you'll want to test it with more data.  I also made assumptions on the datatypes. If yours are different, you'll need to update accordingly.
The CTEs identify the intervals that do not have a sequential partner (different of 1 second between the stop and the next start) for the start and stop times.  It then assigns sequence numbers to those times and joins the start & stop times based on the sequence.

In detail, the 3/1/2006 start time does not have an immediately preceding stop time so it is included and is the first start sequence for its group.  11/1/2008 meets the same criteria and is the next start sequence for its group.  8/31/2008 is the first stop time that does not have a proceeding start time and is the first stop sequence for its group.  Since 3/1/2006 & 8/31/2008 are both the first sequence in their group, they mark the start and stop for the first unbroken interval for the group.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp;
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp (
                     DDEB DATETIME,
                     DFIN DATETIME,
                     CETA INT,
                     AIDNEBHNPRAFI INT
                   );

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('2006-03-01 00:00:00.000', '2006-04-30 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2006-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2006-11-30 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2006-12-01 00:00:00.000', '2007-04-30 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2007-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2008-04-30 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2008-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2008-08-31 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2008-09-01 00:00:00.000', '2008-10-31 23:59:59.000', '2', '231272'),
(' 2008-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2009-04-30 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2009-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2010-01-31 23:59:59.000', '1', '231272'),
(' 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.000', '14', '231272');
WITH Starts AS (
SELECT  *, RowSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ceta, t.AIDNEBHNPRAFI ORDER BY ddeb)
FROM    #temp AS t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   #temp AS It
                     WHERE  t.CETA = It.CETA
                            AND t.AIDNEBHNPRAFI = It.AIDNEBHNPRAFI
                            AND It.DFIN = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, t.DDEB)
                   )
), Finishes AS (

SELECT  *, RowSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ceta, t.AIDNEBHNPRAFI ORDER BY dfin)
FROM    #temp AS t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   #temp AS It
                     WHERE  t.CETA = It.CETA
                            AND t.AIDNEBHNPRAFI = It.AIDNEBHNPRAFI
                            AND t.DFIN = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, it.DDEB)
                   )
)
SELECT Starts.ddeb, Finishes.DFIN,  starts.ceta, starts.AIDNEBHNPRAFI
FROM Starts
INNER JOIN Finishes
ON Starts.AIDNEBHNPRAFI = Finishes.AIDNEBHNPRAFI
AND Starts.CETA = Finishes.CETA
AND Starts.RowSeq = Finishes.RowSeq
ORDER BY Starts.ddeb
```

Results:

```
DDEB    DFIN    CETA    AIDNEBHNPRAFI

2006-03-01 00:00:00.000 2008-08-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272

2008-09-01 00:00:00.000 2008-10-31 23:59:59.000 2   231272

2008-11-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 23:59:59.000 1   231272

2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000 14  231272
```

Answer (score 0):

Wes H got my on the right track. A colleague of mine looked a bit longer at the code and came up with this. And it processes 9,6million rows in 4 mins and 8 secs.

```
With CTETest(StartDate, EndDate, value, ID)
AS
 (
SELECT [DDEB], 
        Case When 
          DFIN = '9999-12-31 23:59:59.000'
          THEN
                       DFIN   
          ELSE 
                 DATEADD(SECOND, 1, [DFIN])
          END
   , [CETA]
   , [AIDNEBHNPRAFI] as ID
FROM [dbo].[TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS]
where DFIN>DDEB and BRRDDEL<>1 and CSTUVRS = 1 
),

T1(ID, value, isStartTS, isEndTS, TS) 
AS (
SELECT ID, value, 1, 0, StartDate
FROM CTETest
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, value, 0, 1, EndDate
FROM CTETest
),

T2 (ID, value, TS,  cr_ttl, prv_ttl) as ( 
select ID, value, TS,
sum(isStartTS) over (Partition by ID, value order by TS,isEndTS rows     unbounded Preceding) -
sum(isEndTS) over (partition by ID, Value order by TS,isEndTS rows unbounded preceding)as cr_ttl, 
 sum(isStartTS) over (Partition by ID, value order by TS,isEndTS rows     between unbounded Preceding and 1 preceding ) -
sum(isEndTS) over (partition by ID, value order by ts,isEndTS rows between     unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)as prv_ttl
from T1 ),

T3 (ID, value, TS, cr_ttl, prv_ttl) as (
Select ID, value, TS, cr_ttl, prv_ttl
from T2 
where cr_ttl = 0 or prv_ttl is null or prv_ttl = 0
),

T4 (ID, value, StartDate ,EndDate, prv_ttl) as ( 
select ID, value, TS, 
 max(TS) over (partition by ID, value order by TS rows between current row     and 1 following),
prv_ttl 
 from T3 
)

select ID as [AIDNEBHNPRAFI], value as CETA,StartDate as DDEB, Case When 
              EndDate = '9999-12-31 23:59:59.000' THEN EndDate ELSE DateADD    (second, -1, EndDate) END as DFIN   
          into     [dbo].[TBYDWHTEBHNPRAFIVRS_CTE]
from T4 
where prv_ttl is Null or prv_ttl = 0 
--order by ID, StartDate
```